# iOS Google Maps SDK - Pinch Gesture zoom effect without scrolling and position changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to make a pinch gesture in GMSMapView without changing the camera target. So I've added a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to block the scrollGestures in GMSUISettings.

```
- (void)zoomGestureHandler:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)
    {

    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"PINCH BEGAN\n");
        _mapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"PINCH END\n");
        _mapView.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {

    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

It is working when slow pinch gestures done. If a user makes a quick pinch gesture the camera jumps away after the zoom animation. Does anyone has an idea how to achieve my goal with a solid solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reaching out google's bug center with the issue, they fixed it with an update.

Get google maps sdk: 1.10.0 or higher.

The solution is to simply add this line when configuring GMSMapview:

```
_mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO;
```

Comment: But map.camera.target still changes for some reason with the SDK 2.7.0 :-( Any suggestions on how to prevent this?